# undefined reference to `Magick::Image::Image()'

Tags: c++, cmake, imagemagick

Подскажите, чего не хватает?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "image.h"
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Magick::Image image;
      try {
        // Read a file into image object
        image.read( "girl.gif" );

        // Crop the image to specified size (width, height, xOffset, yOffset)
        image.crop( Geometry(100,100, 100, 100) );

        // Write the image to a file
        image.write( "x.gif" );
      }
      catch( Exception &error_ )
        {
          cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
          return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

image.cpp

```
#include "image.h"
#include <Magick++.h>

Image::Image()
{

}
```

image.h

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Image
{
public:
    Image();



};

#endif // IMAGE_H
```

CMakeLists.txt
c

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(IimageReadObj)
###add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

find_program(MAGICK_CONFIG "Magick++-config")
# Ask about CXX and lib flags/locations
execute_process(COMMAND "${MAGICK_CONFIG}" "--cxxflags" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS)
execute_process(COMMAND "${MAGICK_CONFIG}" "--libs" OUTPUT_VARIABLE MAGICK_LD_FLAGS)
# Remove trailing whitespace (CMAKE warns about this)
string(STRIP "${MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS}" MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS)
string(STRIP "${MAGICK_LD_FLAGS}" MAGICK_LD_FLAGS)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 ${MAGICK_CXX_FLAGS} ${MAGICK_LD_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall ")


# Create a list with all .cpp source files
set( project_sources
   main.cpp
   image.cpp
)

# Create executable with all necessary source files
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${project_sources}
)

find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

> /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:10:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to `Magick::InitializeMagick(char const*)'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:11:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to`Magick::Image::Image()'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:14:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to
>   `Magick::Image::read(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:17:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to`Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned
>   long, unsigned long, long, long, bool, bool)'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:17:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to `Magick::Image::crop(Magick::Geometry
>   const&)'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:17:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to`Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:20:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to
>   `Magick::Image::write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:11:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to`Magick::Image::~Image()'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:17:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::~Geometry()'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:11:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to`Magick::Image::~Image()'
>   /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/build-IimageReadObj-Desktop_Qt_5_12_0_GCC_64bit-u0412u044bu043fu0443u0441u043a/CMakeFiles/IimageReadObj.dir/main.cpp.o:-1:
>   ошибка: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Magick::Exception' :-1:
>   ошибка: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Знаете, я больше не с ответом, а с вопросом. Вот это вот название хедер файла `#include <Magick++.h>` вообще легально? Я про плюсики. И да, аш-файлы в кавычках двойных импортятся.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` не хватает.

Comment: @AlexSazonov https://imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php

Comment: @shaman888 благодарю.

Comment: @arrowd что какие именно библиотеки подключать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы объявляете в глобальном пространстве имён.

```
using namespace std;
class Image
{
public:
...
};
```

И пользоваться нужно так :

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
::Image image;
}
```

Если вы хотите класс определить в другом пространстве, то так и надо писать.

```
namespace Magick {
class Image
    {
    public:
    ...
    };
}
```

Comment: image.h:7: ошибка: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
 using namespace Magick{
                       ^

Comment: **using** - в переводе искать определения в других пространствах. А **namespace** - это войти чтобы определить в данном пространстве.

Comment: Не знаю как правильно в данном случае задать вопрос, потому здесь пишу. При добавлении #include <iostream> в image.cpp ошибки возвращаются, от чего такое может быть? Magick::Image2::Image2(char **argv)
{
    InitializeMagick(*argv);

Comment: В общем проблема осталась, не знаю почему в прошлый раз ошибки отсутствовали, сейчас все на месте.

Comment: В другом вопросе весь текст проги выложите, скорее всего там другая проблема синтаксиса.

Comment: добавил в  CMakeLists.txt target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES}) Осталась только ошибка /home/alexandr/programming/IimageReadObj/IimageReadObj/main.cpp:17: ошибка: undefined reference to `Magick::Geometry::Geometry(unsigned long, unsigned long, long, long, bool, bool)'